# iif() statement in Access

Tags: ms-access, iif

I have an if statement that is returning a #type! error on my form in Access:

```
IIF([Responsible]=Null,"UNASSIGNED",[Responsible])
```

What I'm trying to achieve is for it return the name of a person assigned to a task (which works without the expression), and when no one is assigned, for it to return the text 'UNASSIGNED'.  I'm not clear on why it isn't working.

Comment: your logic is bad anyways. you can NOT test `null` for equality. null cannot be equal to ANYTHING, include itself. that's why there's `is null`. `iif([responsible] is null, x, y)`

Comment: Nothing can be `=Null` or `!=Null`. `Null` is an unknown value. Use `IsNull()` instead (or `is Null`, as @MarcB mentioned)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just like they said, you can't compare null in VBA, so do it like this:

```
IIF(IsNull([Responsible]),"UNASSIGNED",[Responsible])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the context is an Access form, `Nz` can accomplish what you need more concisely.

```
Nz([Responsible],"UNASSIGNED")
```